# rails HABTM joins and inconveniences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a working HABTM association between the models

Posts and Users... the posts_users table is as advertised and both have the necessary has_and_belongs_to_many in their model.rb

And if I use `User.find(1).posts` it will find all the posts with the valid username

My question is how to deal with this situation.

I want to use

`user.posts.find(1234)` or really from the controller the eq:

```
current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
```

To protect myself from other users jumping around. However this usage has some strange results.  It does work, but instead of the id being a valid id for a particular post or all the posts, it returns the id of 1 instead of say, the real one of 1234.  So further joins such as:

```
user.posts.find(1234).comments
```

don't work or are invalid.

I tried throwing in `all` a few places for good measure, as that has sometimes worked for other awkward situations in the past.  With a few stranger encounters still.

`user.posts.all.first` works and returns the correct ID!, but using first isn't really helpful.  `user.posts.all.find(6933)` returns `#<Enumerable::Enumerator:0x105343630>`

Also tried various combination with `(:post_id => 1234)` returning an id of always 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: rails 2.3.5 in case it matters

Comment: I think the issue is that because it's an association, you will always see an array/enumerable returned.

Comment: Also: if you know the post_id, why do you need to map through the user at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because your join table `posts_users` has an id column. In your migration your join table should look like this:

```
create_table :posts_users, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :posts
  t.references :users
end
```

Comment: That works perfectly thanks!  Except if I attempt to use find() with a friendly_id instead of an ID, friendly_id returns the correct record but with the friendly_id's ID and not the posts.

Comment: Not sure what your exact problem is there, but I have gotten around some of these issues before with an explicit `:select => 'tablename.*'` in the find method to ensure only one table's columns were pulled back.

Answer (score 0):

How about user has many comments through posts. Then something like user.comments.find(:all, :conditions => { :post_id => 1234 }